# General protection error while tring to perform ioctl

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, qemu, ioctl

So After a first attempt to write and read from a PCI with DMA device in the probe function, I tried to write a binary file to the DMA then read it using an *ioctl()*, based on the [edu](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/misc/edu.c) device supplied by QEMU and this [driver](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/master/kernel_modules/qemu_edu.c).

I defined my *ioctls* as follow:

```c
#define IOCTL_LOAD_MODEL   _IOW('q', 1, struct user_data*)
#define IOCTL_READ_MODEL   _IOR('q', 2, struct user_data*)
static long ioctl_load_model(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
  struct test *test = (struct  test*)file->private_data;
  int return_code = 0;
  int buffer_length  = 0;
  dma_addr_t dma_phyisical_address;
  void*  allocated_vaddress;
  int rv;
  pr_info("Welcome to my ioctl\n");
  struct user_data *user_data= (struct user_data*)arg;
    
  pr_info("dma status:%d\n",test->dma_status);
  if(user_data==NULL){
    pr_info("Error user buffer is empty");
    return EFAULT;
  }
  if(user_data->buffer == NULL || user_data->buffer_length == 0){
    pr_info("Error: data structure is empty\n");
    return EFAULT;
  }
  pr_info("buffer length:%ld\n",user_data->buffer_length);
    
  if(test->dma_status == DMA_BUSY){
    pr_info("Error: could not allocate buffer for the dma\n");
    return EINVAL;
  }
  pr_info("DMA is available\n");
  if(user_data->buffer_length > MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH){
    pr_info("Error: currentrly we do not handle big buffers\n");
    return EINVAL;
  }
  buffer_length = user_data->buffer_length;
/* first treat only up to one page sized buufers */
  if(buffer_length > MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH){
    buffer_length = MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH;
  }
  allocated_vaddress = dma_alloc_coherent(&(pdev->dev), 
                                                                              buffer_length,
                                                                             &dma_phyisical_address,
                                                                             GFP_ATOMIC);
  pr_info("checking that memory was allocated properly\n");
  if(allocated_vaddress == NULL){
    pr_info("Error: could not allocate buffer for the dma\n");
    return EINVAL;
  }
  test->allocated_buffer = allocated_vaddress;
  pr_info("allocated data to the buffer:%p\n",dma_phyisical_address);
  pr_info("test info:test->allocated_buffer on initialization %d\n", (*((u32*)test->allocated_buffer)));
  switch (cmd) {
    case IOCTL_LOAD_MODEL:
      pr_info("load model\n");
      /* copy data from userspace to internal buffer now define the ioctl*/
      copy_from_user(user_data->buffer, test->allocated_buffer, buffer_length);
      pr_info("copied data from user");
      iowrite32((u32)dma_phyisical_address, mmio + IO_DMA_SRC);
      iowrite32(DMA_BASE, mmio + IO_DMA_DST);
      iowrite32(buffer_length, mmio + IO_DMA_CNT);
      iowrite32(DMA_CMD | DMA_IRQ, mmio + IO_DMA_CMD);
      test->dma_status = DMA_BUSY;
      rv = wait_event_interruptible_timeout(test->rw_queue, test->dma_status==DMA_FREE, msecs_to_jiffies(1000));
      if(rv < 0){
        pr_info("Error:interrupt was not handled properly, data was not copied\n");
        goto l_release_buffer;
      }
      break;
    case IOCTL_READ_MODEL:
      pr_info("read model\n");
      iowrite32(DMA_BASE, mmio + IO_DMA_SRC);
      iowrite32((u32)dma_phyisical_address, mmio + IO_DMA_DST);
      iowrite32(buffer_length, mmio + IO_DMA_CNT);
      iowrite32(DMA_CMD | DMA_FROM_DEV | DMA_IRQ, mmio + IO_DMA_CMD);
      test->dma_status = DMA_BUSY;
      wait_event_interruptible_timeout(test->rw_queue, test->dma_status!=DMA_BUSY, msecs_to_jiffies(10));
      copy_to_user(user_data->buffer, test->allocated_buffer, buffer_length);
      break;
      default:
        pr_info("Error: unknown command\n");
        goto l_release_buffer;
  }
  dma_free_coherent(&(pdev->dev), user_data->buffer_length, test->allocated_buffer, dma_phyisical_address);
    
  return 0;
    
  l_release_buffer:
    dma_free_coherent(&(pdev->dev), user_data->buffer_length, test->allocated_buffer, dma_phyisical_address);
    return EFAULT;
    
}
```

and also defined a small user code to check out the *ioctl*:

```c
//const size_t TEST_DATA_SIZE = 8;
//const uint8_t test_data[TEST_DATA_SIZE]= {0x86,0x44,0x55,0x11,0x10,0x78,0x96, 0xFE};
    
struct user_data{
  uint8_t *buffer;
  size_t buffer_length;
};
#define IOCTL_LOAD_MODEL   _IOW('q', 1, struct user_data*)
#define IOCTL_READ_MODEL   _IOR('q', 2, struct user_data*)
    
int main(){
  FILE *binary_file;
  struct stat binary_file_stat;
  size_t file_size;
  struct user_data data_to_send;
  struct user_data data_to_receive;
  int ioctl_load_model_rc;
  int ioctl_read_model_rc;
  int exit_code = 0;
  int device_fd = open("/dev/lkmc_pci",O_RDWR);
  if(device_fd < 0){
    printf("could not open device: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit_code = 1;
    goto l_exit;
  }
  binary_file = fopen("main.bin","rb");
  if(NULL == binary_file){
    printf("could not open binary file:%s\n",strerror(errno));
    goto l_close_device;
  }
  fseek(binary_file, 0 , SEEK_END);
  file_size = ftell(binary_file);
  fseek(binary_file, 0 , SEEK_SET);// needed for next read from beginning of file
  printf("file size is:%ld\n", file_size);
  data_to_send.buffer = (uint8_t*) malloc(file_size);
  if(data_to_send.buffer == NULL){
    printf("Error: could not allocate memory for data to send\n");
    exit_code = 1;
    goto l_close_device;
  }
  data_to_send.buffer_length = file_size;
  int read_bytes = fread(data_to_send.buffer,1,data_to_send.buffer_length,binary_file);
  if (read_bytes <=0 || read_bytes != data_to_send.buffer_length){
    printf("Error:read %d/%ld bytes",read_bytes,data_to_send.buffer_length);
    exit_code = 1;
    goto l_release_write;
  }
  printf("read %d bytes\n",read_bytes);
  ioctl_load_model_rc = ioctl(device_fd,IOCTL_LOAD_MODEL, &data_to_send);
  if(ioctl_load_model_rc != 0){
    printf("Error: ioctl to write to device failed");
    exit_code = 1;
    goto l_release_write;
  }
  data_to_receive.buffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(file_size);
  if(data_to_receive.buffer == NULL){
    printf("Error: could not allocate memory for data to receive\n");
    exit_code = 1;
    goto l_release_read;
  }
  data_to_receive.buffer_length = file_size;
  ioctl_read_model_rc = ioctl(device_fd, IOCTL_READ_MODEL, &data_to_receive);
  if(ioctl_read_model_rc != 0){
    printf("Error: could not read data from the device\n");
    goto l_release_read;
  }
  for(int i=0; i <data_to_receive.buffer_length; i++){
    if(data_to_receive.buffer[i] != data_to_send.buffer[i]){
      printf("Error:diff in the %d-th place\n",i);
      exit_code = i + 1;
      goto l_release_read;
    }
  }
  if(exit_code == 0){
    printf("successfull copy\n");
  }
 
    
  l_release_read:
  free(data_to_receive.buffer);
  l_release_write:
    free(data_to_send.buffer);
  l_close_device:
    close(device_fd);
  l_exit:
    return exit_code;
    
  return 0;
}
```

and of course treatment in the irq_handler:

```c
if (test->major == major) {
        irq_status = ioread32(mmio + IO_IRQ_STATUS);
        pr_info("irq_handler irq = %d dev = %d irq_status = %llx\n",
                irq, devi, (unsigned long long)irq_status);
        /* Must do this ACK, or else the interrupts just keeps firing. */
        iowrite32(irq_status, mmio + IO_IRQ_ACK);
        test->dma_status = DMA_FREE;
        wake_up_interruptible(&(test->rw_queue));
```

However, when I try to write to the DMA the *ioctl* I get this error:

```
general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0xff13eb6400029cc0: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
```

when looking at call trace it doesn't make any sense:

```
[   43.512780] Call Trace:
[   43.512780]  _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x1d/0x30
[   43.512780]  prepare_to_wait_event+0x16/0xf0
[   43.512780]  ioctl_load_model+0x313/0x490 [qemu_edu]
[   43.512780]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[   43.512780]  ksys_ioctl+0x8d/0xb0
[   43.512780]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x11/0x20
[   43.512780]  do_syscall_64+0x3e/0x70
[   43.512780]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[   43.512780] RIP: 0033:0x44cc97
[   43.512780] Code: 4f 98 02 00 85 c0 78 df 48 83 c4 08 48 89 d8 5b 5d c3 90 48 89 e8 48 f7 d8 48 39 c3 0f 92 c0 eb b4 66 90 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 c7 c1 c0 ff ff ff f7 d8 64 89 01 48
```

What is going wrong?

edit: here are probe intialization code:

```
static int pci_probe(struct pci_dev *dev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
{
    struct test * test= (struct test*)NULL;
    int rv;

    dev_info(&(dev->dev), "pci_probe\n");
    dev_t dev_number;
    test = (struct  test*)(kmalloc(sizeof(struct test),GFP_KERNEL));
    if(test == NULL){
      pr_info("Could not allocate data structruce for driver, need to ");
      return 1;
    }   
    major = register_chrdev(0, CDEV_NAME, &fops);
    pdev = dev;
    if (pci_enable_device(dev) < 0) {
        dev_err(&(dev->dev), "pci_enable_device\n");
        goto error;
    }
    if (pci_request_region(dev, BAR, "myregion0")) {
        dev_err(&(dev->dev), "pci_request_region\n");
        goto error;
    }
    mmio = pci_iomap(dev, BAR, pci_resource_len(dev, BAR));

    test->major = major;
    if (request_irq(dev->irq, irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "pci_irq_handler0", (void *)test) < 0) {
        dev_err(&(dev->dev), "request_irq\n");
        goto error;
    }
    test->dma_status = DMA_FREE;
    init_waitqueue_head(&queue);
    test->rw_queue = &queue;

    /* Optional sanity checks. The PCI is ready now, all of this could also be called from fops. */
    {
        unsigned i;
        u8 val;

        /* Check that we are using MEM instead of IO.
         *
         * In QEMU, the type is defiened by either:
         *
         * - PCI_BASE_ADDRESS_SPACE_IO
         * - PCI_BASE_ADDRESS_SPACE_MEMORY
         */
        if ((pci_resource_flags(dev, BAR) & IORESOURCE_MEM) != IORESOURCE_MEM) {
            dev_err(&(dev->dev), "pci_resource_flags\n");
            goto error;
        }

        /* 1Mb, as defined by the "1 << 20" in QEMU's memory_region_init_io. Same as pci_resource_len. */
        resource_size_t start = pci_resource_start(dev, BAR);
        resource_size_t end = pci_resource_end(dev, BAR);
        pr_info("start %llx, end %llx, length %llx\n", (unsigned long long)start, (unsigned long long)end, (unsigned long)(end + 1 - start));

        /* The PCI standardized 64 bytes of the configuration space, see LDD3. */
        for (i = 0; i < 64u; ++i) {
            pci_read_config_byte(dev, i, &val);
            pr_info("config %x %x\n", i, val);
        }
        pr_info("dev->irq %x\n", dev->irq);

        /* Initial value of the IO memory. */
        for (i = 0; i < 0x28; i += 4) {
            pr_info("io %x %x\n", i, ioread32((void*)(mmio + i)));
        }
        pci_set_master(dev);
}
    return 0;
 unregister_region:
    unregister_chrdev_region(test->cdev_number, 1);
    return rv;
error:
    return 1;
}

test data structure is:
struct test {
  int major;
  void* allocated_buffer;
  struct cdev cdev;     /* character device embedded struct */
  dev_t cdev_number;/* major:minor*/
  size_t buffer_length;
  dma_status_t dma_status;
  wait_queue_head_t* rw_queue;
};

struct user_data{
  uint8_t *buffer;
  size_t buffer_length;
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224673/discussion-on-question-by-shakedess-general-protection-error-while-tring-to-perf).

Answer (score 0):

As a side node, here are some remarks concerning the source code of the *ioctl()* entry point (those are enhancement suggestions which do not address the "general protection fault" problem):

. The returned errors should be negative. For example:

```c
  if(user_data==NULL){
    pr_info("Error user buffer is empty");
    return -EINVAL;  // Not EINVAL
  }
```

. When the parameters are not valid, you should return -EINVAL (not -EFAULT reserved for bad addresses):

```c
  if(user_data==NULL){
    pr_info("Error user buffer is empty");
    return -EINVAL;
  }
  if(user_data->buffer == NULL || user_data->buffer_length == 0){
    pr_info("Error: data structure is empty\n");
    return -EINVAL;
  }
```

. If the DMA is busy, return -EBUSY (not -EINVAL reserved for bad parameters):

```c
  if(test->dma_status == DMA_BUSY){
    pr_info("Error: could not allocate buffer for the dma\n");
    return -EBUSY;
  }
```

. If the operation is unknown, it is preferable to return **-ENOTTY** as explained [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch06.html) (you are currently returning EFAULT through the *l_release_buffer* label):

> Several kernel functions return -EINVAL (Invalid argument), which makes sense because the command
> argument is indeed not a valid one. The POSIX standard, however, states that if an inappropriate ioctl
> command has been issued, then -ENOTTY should be returned. This error code is interpreted by the
> C library as ´inappropriate ioctl for device', which is usually exactly what the programmer needs to
> hear. It is still pretty common, though, to return -EINVAL in response to an invalid ioctl command.

N.B.: I suppose that you made a typo on the name of the variable *dma_phyisical_address*, it should be *dma_physical_address*

Comment: Other system calls do return `EFAULT` instead of `EINVAL` when passed a NULL pointer where a valid address was expected, so I think that part was correct.  But none of this seems to address the GPF.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I begun my text with "as a side note" to suggest enhancements in the source code but not to provide the answer to the pb. Normally we do it in comments but when it is too long, an answer is preferable.